# What should I use as a suitable placeholder for a NULL WaitHandle with WaitAny?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, waithandle

I'm using `WaitHandle.WaitAny` that accepts an array of `WaitHandle` objects and returns the index of the one event that triggered.

Because the function returns an index, I'd like to keep the index values constant. This causes a problem if a particular slot is empty, because `WaitAny` won't accept an array with a null inside.

Is there a cheap (hopefully no-dispose-needed) `WaitHandle` subclass that simply never triggers? Then I could substitute any null `WaitHandles` I have and keep my handle indexes constant.

(Sure, I could build an `AutoResetEvent` and never trigger it but those aren't cheap and will need disposing.)

Or, will I need to build a registration helper and use variable indexes instead?

Comment: How is this related to `async-await`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado - Replaced tag with "asynchronous". Thanks for spotting the error.

Comment: There is no such class.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you. That would make a good answer if you want the points.